# jQuery form select on change filter table

Tags: jquery, arrays, select, filter, html-table

I have a form with four dropdowns, each with `X` amount of values listed;

**Subject, Type, Month, Location**

And then I have a table with multiple rows pulled from a database with the exact same column headers.

**Subject, Type, Month, Location**

Each row of data is different.

I want to build a filter system where the `$(select).change` function comes in, builds an array of values from all selected dropdowns, and then applys the jquery `hide/show` function wherever it corresponds. The table rows have classes assigned to them dynamically eg:

```
<tr class="subjectVal typeVal monthVal locationVal"><td>lorem ipsum</td>...</tr>
```

At the moment I have:

```
$("form select").change(function() {

    var values = [];        
    $("form select").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "Please select...") {
            values.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

    $("table.events tr.row").each(function() {
        tr = $(this);
        $.each( values, function(index, item){
            if (!$(tr).hasClass(item)) {
                $(tr).hide();

            } else {
                $(tr).show();
            }
        });

    });

});
```

But this if the value array contains more than one item, only that item is filtering the table. If I choose a subject, then choose a location, it will always show all of those locations regardless of the subject I have chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically it should only show the row if all values match? If so then this code should work:

```
$("table.events tr.row").each(function() {
    var tr = $(this), show = true;
    $.each( values, function(index, item){
        if (!tr.hasClass(item)) {
            show = false;
        }
    });
    tr.toggle(show);
});
```